# AppEngine and Django: including a template file

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates, include

As the title suggests, I'm using Google App Engine and Django.

I have quite a bit of identical code across my templates and would like to reduce this by including template files. So, in my main application directory I have the python handler file, the main template, and the template I want to include in my main template.

I would have thought that including {% include "fileToInclude.html" %} would work on its own but that simply doesn't include anything. I assume I have to set something up, maybe using TEMPLATE_DIRS, but can't figure it out on my own.

EDIT:

I've tried:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'), )
```

But to no avail. I'll try some other possibilities too.

Comment: does the file "templates/fileToInclude.html" exist?

Comment: Yes; and I also put the file in the root directory. I've tried including both fileToInclude.html and templates/fileToInclude.html.

Comment: Are you using Django 0.96 templates (included with App Engine), or one of the App-Engine-Django helpers (in which case, which one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it works "out of the box" if I don't load Templates first and render them with a Context object. Instead, I use the standard method shown in the [AppEngine tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html).

Answer (score 3):

First, you should consider using [template inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) rather than the `include` tag, which is often appropriate but sometimes far inferior to template inheritance.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with App Engine, but from my experience with regular Django, I can tell you that you need to set your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` list to include the folder from which you want to include a template, as you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and tracked it down into the ext.webapp package.  In template.py, you'll find this comment on line 33:

Django uses a global setting for the directory in which it looks for templates.
This is not natural in the context of the webapp module, so our load method
takes in a complete template path, and we set these settings on the fly
automatically.  Because we have to set and use a global setting on every
method call, this module is not thread safe, though that is not an issue
for applications.

See line 92 in the same file.  You can see the template dirs being squashed:

```
directory, file_name = os.path.split(abspath)
new_settings = {
    'TEMPLATE_DIRS': (directory,),
    'TEMPLATE_DEBUG': debug,
    'DEBUG': debug,
    }
```

UPDATE:  Here is the workaround which worked for me - http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/c3e0e4c47e4f3680/262b517a723454b6?lnk=gst&q=template_dirs#262b517a723454b6

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following to get around using includes:

```
def render(file, map={}):
  return template.render(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../templates', file), map)  

table = render("table.html", {"headers": headers, "rows": rows})   
final = render("final.html", {"table": table})

self.response.out.write(final)
```